# I can't correctly set float type variables when entering them in custom component text boxes

Tags: c#

I can't correctly set the variables when I set the value in custom component boxes.

The expected result: e.g.

I receive 300.00 in a custom textbox, and I replace 300.00 by 100.00, the expected result when I click on the button must be 100.00, but the real result is 0.00.

I declare these variables in SetVar.cs that is my class.

```
float t1, t2, t3, t4;
```

This is the constructor where I receive the initial values from the previous form:

```
  public SetVar(float x1, float x2, float x3, float x4)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            row_var1.Value1 = x1;
            row_var1.Value2 = x2;
            row_var2.Value1 = x3;
            row_var2.Value2 = x4;
        }
```

And in this portion of code you have to pay close attention. What I want is to set the text box assigning it the floating value that I want and that is not zero, I am doing the validation and setting wrong. I know. But in this code is the real problem. The values ​​when clicking on the button should be modified to the value with which I edit the text boxes and not with zero.

```
public float T1
    {
        get
        {
            return t1;
        }
        set
        {

            t1 = value;

        }
    }
    public float T2
    {

        get
        {
            return t2;
        }
        set
        {

            t2 = value;

        }
    }
    public float T3
    {

        get
        {
            return t3;
        }
        set
        {

            t3 = value;

        }
    }
    public float T4
    {
        get
        {
            return t4;
        }
        set
        {

            t4 = value;

        }
    }
```

This is the setter I'm setting the values:

```
   public void setValues()
        {
        this.row_var1.Value1 = T1;
        this.row_var1.Value2 = T2;
        this.row_var2.Value1 = T3;
        this.row_var2.Value2 = T4;
        }
```

And by last, this is the button that calls "Setting values". Here I'm setting the values in another form.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.setValues();

        var frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Main>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (frm != null)
        {
            frm = new Main(this.row_var1.Value1, this.row_var1.Value2,
                this.row_var2.Value1, this.row_var2.Value2,
           );

            frm.Activate();

        }
        Close();
    }
```

but you must pay attention to this code:

```
 public float T1
    {
        get
        {
            return t1;
        }
        set
        {

            t1 = value;

        }
    }
    public float T2
    {

        get
        {
            return t2;
        }
        set
        {

            t2 = value;

        }
    }
    public float T3
    {

        get
        {
            return t3;
        }
        set
        {

            t3 = value;

        }
    }
    public float T4
    {
        get
        {
            return t4;
        }
        set
        {

            t4 = value;

        }
    }
```

Variables should be set to a user entered value and not zero. These are t1, t2, t3 and t4 and must be stored in textboxes' values row_var1.Value1, row_var1.Value2, row_var2.Value1 and row_var2.Value2, respectively.

Can someone provide a precise solution so that the values ​​initialized in the constructor can be set by values ​​entered by the user and not by zero as it happens with the code in T1, T2, T3, T4 {get, set} ?

Comment: Nowhere in the code shown do you connect the T1 etc. properties to your textboxes. The default value for a float in C# is 0.0. This is what you feed to your second form on the button click event.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand. Can you show all classes involved?

Comment: the problem is I don't know how set initial values charged in constructor by input values entried by user. I know the default value In setters of T1 T2 T3 and T4 is 0.00. the assigned values to t1 t2 t3 and t4 in T1 T2 T3 and T4 setters respectively must be values entried by user. Values typed at the moment when the user sets the initial values in text boxes that were initialized in constructor.